# Where can I access location data for aquaculture sites across Europe?

Tags: data, europe

Where can I access location data for aquaculture sites across Europe?

Ideally there might be, though I haven't been able to see, a dataset held by the EU identifying every aquaculture site (sites such as shellfish farms) across Europe. The only place I have been able to find spatial information on this topic is at [Marine Scotland National Marine Plan interactive map](https://marinescotland.atkinsgeospatial.com/nmpi/) (for Scotland only).

The primary countries I need this information for are:
Norway, Sweden, Denmark, Germany, Netherlands, United Kingdom, Faroe Islands.

Currently I have looked through the GeoNames database, queried EEA and been googling away at the problem.

Has anyone seen datasets of this nature for the above mentioned countries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find any spatial datasets for Europe, one resource you should at least look at is the [INSPIRE geoportal](http://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/discovery/)

I found 350 results for the term **Aquaculture** using the discovery tool

Comment: This is a really good resource! Thanks very much for pointing out the INSPIRE geoportal